# lighttpd not making global environment variables availble to executables

Tags: linux, cgi, environment-variables, server, lighttpd

How to set up lighttpd in order to make environment variables available to spawned processes?

I have an executable being called through CGI as an URL (e.g. http://.../cgi-bin/executable.bin).

The executable needs to load libraries and read environment variables that are set in `/etc/profile` using `export FOO=BAR`.

When I try to access the URL, it generates Internal Server Error (500), caused by an empty environment variable, which are properly set in `/etc/profile`.

Answer (score 8):

I ended up enabling `mod_setenv` in `modules.conf` and including each environment variable I needed like this:

```
##
## mod_setenv
##
setenv.add-environment = ( "PATH" => env.PATH,
                           "WSFC_HOME" => env.WSFC_HOME,
                           "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" => env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH )
```